# Why there is no GLFW_REPEAT for the mouse?

Tags: c++, glfw

It seems natural to have such functionality for mouse button being hold but this functionality is solely for key event. According to the glfw documentation:

> #define GLFW_REPEAT   2
>
> The key was held down until it repeated.

But the press and release buttons, we have which address both the keyboard and mouse inputs.

> #define GLFW_PRESS   1
>
> The key or mouse button was pressed.
>
> #define GLFW_RELEASE   0
>
> The key or mouse button was released.

I would like to know if there is a workaround for this issue. Moreover, why this functionality is ignored with the mouse.

Answer (score 6):

Ask yourself, what is the frequency at which `GLFW_REPEAT` triggers? The right answer is that this frequency depends on your user's settings. It is exactly the frequency at which characters will appear in any input field in any application if you hold a character key. So the only purpose of `GLFW_REPEAT` is to implement printing in your application and make it look consistent with all other applications on the machine. You definitely should not use `GLFW_REPEAT` to implement WASD controls and other things like that.

Why is there no `GLFW_REPEAT` for mouse? Because there is probably no OS or desktop environment with a concept of repeated mouse input. If you want one, just remember the state of mouse buttons when handling press and release events and generate repeat "events" manually with a desired frequency. Do it every frame if you wish, or even faster, if you have a separate input thread.

Comment: I love you. I was trying to figure this out for a long time